# Backup problem after moving Azure VM to a new resource group

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-keyvault, bitlocker, azure-backup-vault

I have the following scenario:

- I have one Azure windows VM
- I have encrypted the disk and created a keyvault in the same resource group
- I have moved all the VM (plus related resourcer) + keyvault to a new resource group

And now I can't configure backup from recovery vault and i have the following error:

> Could not locate key vault (xxxxxxxx-KeyVault) associated with this
>   virtual machine

Any suggestions are welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using disks that are encrypted. Although you can move keyvaults to new resource groups or subscriptions you cannot do it if the vault is used for disk encryption

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

[image]

You will likely need to remove the backup for that machine and create a new one from scratch.

Comment: I Know what it says in the documentation but I was able to successfully move the keyvault to another resource group.

Comment: Yes you moved it but it doesn't work properly as you found.